# How can I convert mouse Position from SFML to OpenGL coordinate?

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I want to move a box follow the mouse position but I don't know how to convert position that I get from sf::Mouse::getPosition() to the coordinate in OpenGL

Comment: your screen coordinates are 2D, and the opengl ones are 3D. A whole cone of opengl points maybe converted to a given screen pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, try using the `gluUnproject` function from the GLU library. Otherwise, you will need to reimplement it by computing the inverse matrices of both modelview and projection, then apply them in reverse order (ie. reverse projection then reverse modelview) to your screen point. You may have to add an extra step to convert the window canvas coordinates back to the projection screen coordinates (that step depends on your projection setup).

I provided a sample programme using SDL and `gluUnproject` in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/24554752).

Note that:

- the modelview inverse can be computed trivially by successivelly applying the opposit transformations in the reverse order.

  For instance, if you set your modelview from identity first by an  translation, then an  rotation, all  you need to do is to set it to the <-a,-b,-c> rotation, and then apply the <-x,-y,-z> translation to get the inverse modelview.
- For the projection inverse matrix, [the red book appendix F](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/appendixf.html) - pointer courtesie of [that gamedev.net page](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/517310-inverse-of-projection-matrix/) (though the link is broken there) - gives a solution.

This will only provide you the matrices to unproject a point from the homogeneous opengl projection space. You need first to pick a point from that space. That point maybe chosen using the screen cordinates first transformed back into the projection space. In my example, this involves flipping the coordinates with regards to the canvas dimension (but things could be perhaps different with another projection setup) and then extending them to 3D by adding a carefully chosen z component.

That said, in the example programme of the other question, the goal was to cast a ray passing through the projected pixel into the scene, and figure out the distance from that line to points in the scene, and pick the closest one. You might be able to avoid the whole unproject business, by noticing that the mouse always move in the camera projection plan. Hence the translation vector for the object will necessary be composed of the *X* and *Y* unit vectors of the camera (I am assuming that *Z* is the axis perpendicular to the screen, as usual in OpenGL), both scaled by factor depending on the distance of the object to the camera.

You will get something like that:

```
    +--------+   object translation plane
    |        /
    |       /
    |      /
    |     /
    +----+  screen plane
    |    /
    |   /
    |  /
    | /
    + camera eye position
```

You can get the scaling factor from the [Intercept theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem), and the *X* and *Y* camera vectors from the first and second columns of the modelview matrix.

The final translation vector should be something along the lines of:

```
T = f * (dx * X + dy * Y)
```

where `f` is the scaling factor, `X` and `Y` the camera vectors, and `<dx,dy>` the mouse coordinates delta vector in the projection space.

Answer (score 1):

You know your window resolution, and the mouse position relative to the window. From there you can determine a normalized coordinate in [0,1]. From this coordinate, you can then project a ray into your scene, and using the inverse of your projection*view matrix, can turn this into a world-space ray.

Then it is up to you to intersect the world space ray against your scene objects (via collision detection) to determine the "clicked on" objects (note that there may be more than one due to depth; usually you want the closest hit). This all depends on how you have organized your scene's spatial information and this is all made faster if you have some spatial partitioning structures (e.g. octree or BSP) for quick culling and simplified bounding boxes (e.g. AABBs or spheres) on your "scene objects" for a fast broad phase.

I would say more, but "the coordinate in OpenGL" is highly underspecified. Usually, you are not only interested in the coordinate, but also the "scene object" it meaningfully belongs to, and a whole bunch of other properties.